# CapWords conventions: get_MyClass or get_my_class

Tags: python, coding-style

This is a style conventions question.

PEP8 convention for a class definition would be something like

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, attri):
        self.attri = attri
```

So say I want to write a module-scoped function which takes some data, processes it, and then creates an instance of MyClass.

PEP8 says that my function definitions should have lowercase_underscore style names, like

```
def get_my_class(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    pass
```

But my inclination would be to make it clear that I'm talking about MyClass instances like so

```
def get_MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    pass
```

For this case, it looks trivially obvious that my_class and MyClass are related, but there are some cases where it's not so obvious. For example, I'm pulling data from a spreadsheet and have a SpreadsheetColumn class that takes the form of a heading attribute and a data list attribute. Yet, if you didn't know I was talking about an instance of the SpreadsheetColumn class, you might think that I'm talking about a raw column of cells as they might appear in an Excel sheet.

I'm wondering if it's reasonable to violate PEP8 to use `get_MyClass`. Being new to Python, I don't want to create a habit for a bad naming convention.

I've searched PEP8 and Stack Overflow and didn't see anything that addressed the issue.

Comment: Does it make sense to call it `get_SpreadsheetColumn()`? Doesn't `get_column()` work just as well? Describe what the object represents in the function name, not what type it is.

Comment: @Eric The problem in my case it that I have a spreadsheet full of coordinates that describe a layout on a page. So I could be talking about a column in the spreadsheet, a column of coordinates or a column in the final layout. In my case it's a distinction that matters

Comment: I wouldn't use get_MyClass() because "MyClass" is the class, not the instance.  At first reading get_MyClass() would not be a MyClass factory, but instead would be some sort of decorator which, based upon runtime information, returned a class that derived from MyClass (or was MyClass).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the usage of the function, it might be more appropriate to turn it into a [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) or `staticmethod`.  Then it's association with the `class` is clear, but you don't violate any naming conventions.

e.g.:

```
class MyClass(object):
     def __init__(self,arg):
         self.arg = arg

     @classmethod
     def from_sum(cls,*args):
         return cls(sum(args))

inst = MyClass.from_sum(1,2,3,4)
print inst.arg  #10
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the kind of thing that classmethods are for.

Comment: This is the way to go for alternate constructors. But those are actually pretty rare. Far more often, you didn't actually need a `MyClass` or `SpreadsheetColumn` instance in the first place. Python is designed around duck typing, and it's usually (not always, but usually) the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back. Usually, you don't want to do this *at all*, so the naming convention is the least of your worries.

First, normally, you don't care what actual class or type something is. This is what duck typing is all about. You don't want a `SpreadsheetColumn` instance, you want something that you can use as a spreadsheet column. It may be an instance of `SpreadsheetColumn`, or of a subclass, or of some proxy class, or of some mock class for testing—whatever it is, you don't care, as long as it looks and works like a column.

Notice that, even in static languages like Java and C#, factory functions (or objects) usually don't create an instance of a specific *class*, they create an instance of *any class that implements a specific interface*. In Python, that's usually implicit. (And, when it's not, it's usually because you're using something like PEAK or Twisted, and you should follow their coding style for protocols or interfaces.)

So, your factory function should be called `get_column`, not `get_SpreadsheetColumn`.

When the function is more of an "alternate constructor" than a factory, then mgilson's answer is the way to go. See `chain()` and `chain.from_iterable()` in `itertools` from a good standard library example.

But notice that this isn't very common in the standard library, most of the popular modules on PyPI, etc. And there's a good reason. Usually, you can just use a single constructor with default-valued parameters, keyword parameters, or at worst `*args` and `**kwargs`. If this makes the API too confusing for human readers, or too ambiguous to code, that's when you need an alternate constructor. Otherwise, you don't.

Sometimes, you really *do* need a factory that creates objects of a concrete type, and that concrete type is a part of the interface that the caller needs to know about. As I mentioned above, this is pretty rare even in static languages, and it's even rarer in Python, but it does come up. And then, you really do need an answer to your original question.

In that case, I think I *would* name the function something ugly and unusual like `get_MyClass` or `get_MyClass_instance`. It ought to stick out immediately, because anyone reading my code will probably need to figure out why I'm explicitly getting a `MyClass` instead of a `thing` in order to understand the rest of my code.

Comment: Hi @abarnert, thanks for taking the time to respond. I've been reading up on duck typing. What I gather: rather than hard-coding objects by form, you just expect them to behave like the form in question, and presumable allow errors to take place which are appropriately handled if that's not the case. Makes sense, but I have no idea what that looks like for my application. Details to follow

Comment: I'm generating XML(ish) files that are exported from a proprietary industrial touchscreen gui application, parsing them into a logical form, extracting out meaningful objects to be used as templates. Then I have a spreadsheet where the user specifies settings specific to that project, and I generate batches of XML files that can import into that program. All in all I feel like the form has very little flexibility. I don't know cases where I would need to treat a mallard as a duck. What do you think?

Comment: @BenMordecai: I'm not sure what exactly your object model is here, but I think you're saying that you have things like `XMLDocument` and `XMLNode` and `SpreadsheetCell` for which there is no obvious reason you'd ever have a compatible but different type. But think about testing. If your spreadsheet code worked on any object with the right interface, you could pass in mock cells, which may be much easier to generate from unit test code than actual `SpreadsheetCell` objects. I'm not sure whether this is helpful or not, but it's hard without more details…